# echo $SHELL: unexpected result

Tags: command-line, csh

I am facing a problem related to the shell change, when I change the shell from bash to csh and type the comand `echo $SHELL`, I expect the shell to print:

```
/bin/csh
```

But instead it prints:

```
/bin/bash
```

What is the reason for that? How do I print the path to the currently running shell instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "change shell"?

Comment: It is still showing the shell which is in your environment variable...you need to do make the change in the .profile or .bashrc* and then '. .profile' or '. .bashrc*' and then try echoing that change.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns your default shell.

Comment: @choroba i mean using csh shell instead of bash or any shell , change scripting language

Comment: @Ashu , What i know that $SHELL Contains the type of the shell and updated when the shell changes

Comment: echo $SHELL Only print the default shell thanks , what is the command to display the type of the shell

Answer (score 1):

To view your current shell use:

```
echo $0
```

`$SHELL` prints the default shell.